# Mysql delete all posts that have a given meta_key

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a wordpress site that has some meta_key's asigned to my posts. I want to delete all posts in mysql that has the `meta_key` value `acest_meta`. With this SQL command :

```
SELECT `post_id`
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key` 
LIKE 'acest_meta' 
ORDER BY `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` ASC
```

i can see all the id's that contain that given meta_key but i don't have a delete check box neer. I see a message on top that say "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available." How can i delete all those posts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Mysql query you can use join in delete query

```
DELETE p.*,w.*
FROM `wp_postmeta` w
JOIN wp_posts p
 ON(p.ID = w.`post_id`)
WHERE w.`meta_key` LIKE 'acest_meta'
```

Above query will delete all posts and its meta data contains  a meta_key as acest_meta

Comment: +1 for a different way to do it with a join :)

Answer (score 4):

you can delete with a select using an IN() statement and put the select in an IN like so

```
DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE `post_id` IN 
(   SELECT `post_id`
    FROM `wp_postmeta`
    WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'acest_meta' 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from wp_postmeta
 where post_id in
       (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'acest_meta')
```

Comment: same for you :) we had the same idea :)